# how to parse the json data using php I want to parse formattedAmount and currencyCode

Tags: php, json, foreach

```
    "deals": [
     {   
        "soldQuantity": 1000,
        "shippingAddressRequired": false,
    "options": [
        {
        "value": {
                    "formattedAmount": "$43.78",
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "amount": 4378
                },
        },
    ],
},
]
```

I want to parse formattedAmount and currencyCode using php foreach loop

my code gives error :-`Trying to get property of non-object`

the code is

```
   $json = file_get_contents('../jsonfile/product.json');
   $json_string = json_decode($json);
   foreach($json_string->deals as $mydata)
   {
      foreach($mydata->options->value as $option)
  {                              
   echo $option->;
  }
   }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include the actual error message.

Comment: That is some horrible-looking JSON.

Comment: @user3719363, that JSON is not legal. It is very broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `foreach($mydata->options->value as $option)` because value is not array.
Do:

```
foreach($mydata->options as $option) {
    echo $option->value->formattedAmount;
    echo $option->value->currencyCode;
    echo $option->value->amount;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I try it it also gives the same above error:-Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Edited my answer so you'll understand what I mean

Comment: hello yaniv there are many options each contain several value array contain several what I do if I want only 1rst array value

Answer (score 0):

Because the values of `deals` and `options` are arrays, you need to say:

```
foreach($mydata->options[0]->value as $option)
```

Your json is poorly formatted, by the way. Arrays should not have a comma after them, as your `options` array does. That alone will cause you problems.

A `foreach` is not really needed here, since there's only one value in the `deals` array, and only one in the `options` array.

Comment: thanks for reply. no they not one and the other thing is it again gives error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @user3719363, yes, there is only one value in the arrays you've listed. Which line number does it say the error occurs in? You chopped off the end of the error message.